# Li element was removed, alert say not

Tags: jquery

I  still have a problem:

```
var parent = $(this).parent(); // li element
parent.remove();
if ($( "#cart ol" ).find("li")) {
    alert('exists');
}
```

Although all li was removed (and become invisible), alert still appears. Why?

Comment: `.find()` always returns a jQuery object (no matter whether elements have been selected or not) which always evaluates to `true`.

Comment: justi.... Do you mind accept the answer that helped you checking on the green 'V' mark beside the Answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
if ($( "#cart ol" ).find("li").length) {
    alert('exists');
}
```